# При создании проекта Android.Studio мне сразу вылазят ошибки

Tags: java, android-studio

Я только создал проект и мне сразу открылось окно где ошибка на ошибке и ничего не хочет работать
Вот код:

```
package com.example.vuraddo.karasevbluetooth;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Вот все выходит в ошибках:

```
Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
Versions that do not match:
    26.0.0-alpha1
    25.3.1
    25.3.0
    25.2.0
    25.1.1
    + 50 more
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/VURADDO/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
    file:/C:/Users/VURADDO/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
    file:/C:/Users/VURADDO/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
    file:/C:/Users/VURADDO/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
    file:/C:/Users/VURADDO/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
Required by:
    project :app

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager
```

Comment: приложите код текстом а не картинкой, это раз, два - у вас в градл есть такая строка - `implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1"` или что-то типа нее?

Comment: Я исправил как вы и просили

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перейдите в `Tools >> Android >> SDK Manager` и как говорится в ошибке:

```
Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

установите `Android Support Repository` как показано здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот есть [документация](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup) и [туториал](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/en/Unit%201/33_c_the_android_support_library.html) по вашему вопросу.

### UPDATE

Переходим в файл `app/build.gradle` и там ставим:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0'
```

и в втором `build.gradle` добавляем в группу:

```
buildscript {
repositories {

mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {                                  // <-- Add this
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
```

и в

```
allprojects {
repositories {

maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
```

вот есть такой же [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365927/could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-android-supportappcompat-v727).

Comment: Он у меня был установлен

Comment: а какие у вас библиотеки установлены?

Comment: Я сейчас поставил на загрузку все от Android 4.0 и выше
Или вы не об этом?

Comment: нет, просто нужно понимать что у вас есть уже а чего нет в проекте, так же попробуйте почистить кэш проекта и перезагрузите ide

Comment: Я вот только недавно скачал Андройд студио и запустил этот проект

Comment: а вы вообще библиотеки ставили какие-то при установке? там предлагалось установить библиотеки?

Comment: Нет, я просто скачал, создал новый проект и вот теперь я тут)

Comment: между скачиванием и созданием проекта есть установка)) в процессе установки было окошко, где вы выбирали компоненты для установки, там нужно выбирать установку sdk тоже :)

Comment: Я выбрал создать новый проект -> назвал его -> выбрал стиль (ну там тип как оно будет выглядеть) -> потом там было окошко с выбором версии андройдна(наверно) -> нажал финиш

Comment: @ВладКарасёв, обновил ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: я попытался сделать как вы мне сказали, но ошибка не ушла.
Если навестись на эти красные слова, то на 'AppCompatActivity' предлагает создать  класс, на '@Override' создать метод,  на 'setContentView' переименовать, а где выделенная красная R  он просто не понимает что это